# django - file upload fails when its being opened from a template using {% include "file_upload.html%" %}

Tags: django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

When uploading a file by opening the **`file_upload.html`** template directly which contains the *html* form the server gives the following message:

```
[13/Nov/2022 08:00:54] "POST /upload_view/ HTTP/1.1" 200 948 and I see the file in the media root folder.
```

When doing the same thing but opening up **`index.html`** which uses `{% include %}` to bake in the **`file_upload.html`** I see this:

```
[13/Nov/2022 08:02:59] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1538 and **no** uploaded file in media root folder.
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

My views:

```py
def index_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

```py
def upload_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_file = request.FILES['filename']
        stored_file = FileSystemStorage()
        stored_file.save(user_file.name, user_file )
    return render(request, "file_upload.html", {})
```

my templates:

**index.html**

```html
{% extends "base_template.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>this is a test</p>

{%  include "file_upload.html" %}

{%  endblock %}
```

**file_upload.html**

```html
{% block content %}
<p>Upload</p>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--cross site request forgery documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/csrf/-->
    {%  csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <button type="submit"> Upload file</button>
</form>

{%  endblock %}
```

URL patterns in `urls.py` module:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index_view, name='index'),
    path('index/', index_view, name='index'),
    path('upload_view/', upload_view, name='fileupload'),
    path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('static/favicon/favicon.ico')))
```

Comment: Python code snippets can be highlighted using ```python at the beginning.  The codes look nicer if you use it.
Can't be the one additional % the problem? I mean in the title there is a % after the file name, if it's the same in your file... Well, I guess then there should be an error message.

Comment: - added ```python to the python code blocks
- ive changed my code to remove the {% extends "base_template.html" %} from  file_upload.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding the line upload_view(request) to my index_view:

```py
def index_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    upload_view(request)
    return render(request, "index.html", {})
```